# Select where id not in list for IntIdTable in Kotlin Exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

In Kotlin exposed, I have a IntIdTable like this:

```
object UserTable : IntIdTable("user", "id") {
    override val id: Column<EntityID<Int>>
        get() = super.id
    val name = varchar("name", 128)
    val activeFlg = integer("active_flg")
    ...
}
```

So, I call the transaction that get all record from test table with exclude ids like this:

```
fun getAllWithExcludeIds(excludeIds: List<Int>): List<User> {
    return transaction {
        UserTable
            .select { UserTable.id notInList excludeIds }
    }
}
```

Then I got a type miss match error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
EntityID<Int>
Found:
Int
```

How can I select list of users which has id not in specified excludeIds list? Thank you!

Comment: I just copied your example (renamed the table ```TestTable``` to ```UserTable``` in the query) and run the code. It works: ```SELECT "USER".ID, "USER"."NAME", "USER".ACTIVE_FLG FROM "USER" WHERE "USER".ID NOT IN (1, 2)```
Which version of exposed do you use? I use 0.26.1.

Comment: Oh, I'm using 0.11.2?

Comment: So you should upgrade.

Comment: I will upgrade it, thank you!